# get correct values in childcursor for clicked group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I can use `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` to create `ExpandableListView` with correct groupcursors and childcursors. For my program, each child contains three `TextView`s. When I expand group and click on child, I use custom dialog to show the three values in `EditText` view.

The program is ok if I only open "ONE" group at a time. I can get correct child values if clicked. But if I expand several groups at the same time. It only shows the latest children under latest group.

For example: Group A has 3 items, Group B has 5 items, Group C has 2 items. First I clicked on children under Group A, no problem, then children under Group B, no problem, but if I go back to click children under Group A, it still shows child under Group B. I don't know how can show correct children. If I use Toast to display, all children are correct, so strange. What can I do in this methods ?

```
epView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long row) 
            { 
             return false;  
            }
            });

        epView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) 
        {

         int tempid = childcursor.getInt(0);
         String temp1 = childcursor.getString(1);
            String temp2 = childcursor.getString(2);
            String temp3 = childcursor.getString(3);
            CustomDialog custom = new CustomDialog(ListCateActivity.this,catecursor,childcursor,temp1,temp2,temp3,tempid);
            custom.setTitle("Record Information");
            custom.show();

            Toast.makeText(ListCateActivity.this, "Group:"+String.valueOf(groupPosition).toString()+" Child: "+String.valueOf(childPosition).toString()+temp1+" "+temp2+" "+temp3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        });
```

thanks !!

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Answer (score 0):

Finally I know what happened to my code now, but it is so strange. As I define childcursor in getChildrenCursor method. It should be inherited as I define childcursor as instance variable, so it can be shared among the class. Anyway, Java and Android is interesting. But when you are stuck with unexpected result, you need to debug to find out what the problem is.